# Linq query with exist needed

Tags: c#, linq, exists

I am trying to write a LINQ query to get some data. The SQL query that I am trying to convert to LINQ is:

```
SET HApps = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM [App] r                                
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM AppStatus laa
              WHERE laa.AppID = r.AppID
      AND laa.AppCode = 3))
```

Is there any way to write Exist clause in LINQ?

EDIT:
My situation is little different then this answer because I have to get the count. I am trying to do something like this but it is not working

```
from r in
(from r in context.App
  where
    (from laa in context.AppStatus
     where
       laa.AppId == r.AppId && laa.AppId == 3
                                select new
                                {
                                    Column1 = 1
                                }).FirstOrDefault().Column1 != null
                        select new
                        {
                            Column1 = 1,
                            Dummy = "x"
                        })
                    group r by new {r.Dummy}
                    into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Column1 = g.Count()
                    };
```

Comment: LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities? It kind of makes a difference.

Comment: It is LINQ to entities but my situation is little different. I have edited the question to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Sql and the naming of your DbSets you could do this (its a Lamda).

```
context.App.Count(x => context.AppStatus.Any(y => y.AppId == x.AppId && y.AppId ==3));
```

*I have no idea what that mess is underneath in your c# code and there is no explanation on it or corresponding Sql from your sql statement so I am going to ignore it.*